# CASE WHEN in MS Access SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm writing a query using MS Access SQL and MS Access doesn't recognize my query.

So I want to have something like this:

```
If salutation = 1 Then
    salutation ='Mr'
ElseIf salutaion = 2 Then
    salutaion ='Mme'
ElseIf salutaion = 3 Then
    Salutation = 'Mlle'
Else
   Salution = 'ND'
```

And Then I entered the following query:

```
CASE WHEN (BN_CS_MP_MASTERPROFILE.CMP_SALUTATION='1') THEN 'Mr'
WHEN (BN_CS_MP_MASTERPROFILE.CMP_SALUTATION='2') THEN 'Mme'
WHEN (BN_CS_MP_MASTERPROFILE.CMP_SALUTATION='3') THEN 'Mlle'
ELSE 'ND' END
```

Any help will be welcome!

Answer (score 2):

Use `switch`:

```
SWITCH(BN_CS_MP_MASTERPROFILE.CMP_SALUTATION = '1', 'Mr',
       BN_CS_MP_MASTERPROFILE.CMP_SALUTATION = '2', 'Mme',
       BN_CS_MP_MASTERPROFILE.CMP_SALUTATION = '3', 'Mlle'
       1=1, 'ND'
      )
```

Note:  If `CMP_SALUTATION` is declared as a number of any type, then remove the single quotes on the comparison.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the [`Choose`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/choose-function-76230415-910f-463a-a799-cf7e90aa7fd4) function in the following way:

```
Nz(Choose(BN_CS_MP_MASTERPROFILE.CMP_SALUTATION,'Mr','Mme','Mlle'),'ND')
```

Answer (score 0):

If your version/setup of Access does not support `SWITCH`, then consider using `IIF` instead:

```
IFF(BN_CS_MP_MASTERPROFILE.CMP_SALUTATION = "1", "Mr",
    IIF(BN_CS_MP_MASTERPROFILE.CMP_SALUTATION = "2", "Mme",
        IIF(BN_CS_MP_MASTERPROFILE.CMP_SALUTATION = "3", "Mlle", "ND")))
```